Chromebook RW_Legacy enabled Jammy 22.04 install
With Development enabled and enabling Legacy settings for RW_Legacy, I installed a minimal from a live Ubuntu Jammy X86_64 image installed from usb.
I get a clean boot and have updated with libraries base GIT, Android Studio, and Utils. My question is I have a 64GB SDcard with 57GB free formatted with exfatprogs util to ext4.
My question is, after selecting to boot from internal storage, is it needed to alter the fstab and mount, how best can I address path issues with Android utils installed with the optimal file permissions to sync with GIT?
here is df output
    $ df -ah
df: /run/user/1000/doc: Operation not permitted
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           378M  2.4M  375M   1% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2   29G   26G  1.2G  96% /
securityfs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs           1.9G   38M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
cgroup2            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup
pstore             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
efivarfs         64K  2.5K   57K   5% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
bpf                0     0     0    - /sys/fs/bpf
systemd-1          -     -     -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
mqueue             0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
hugetlbfs          0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
debugfs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tracefs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/tracing
configfs           0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
fusectl            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1822
/dev/loop4      241M  241M     0 100% /snap/firefox/2356
/dev/loop5      269M  269M     0 100% /snap/firefox/4451
/dev/loop8       50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/18357
/dev/loop9      512K  512K     0 100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157
/dev/loop10      39M   39M     0 100% /snap/snapd/21759
/dev/mmcblk0p2   29G   26G  1.2G  96% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
/dev/loop7      302M  302M     0 100% /snap/qt5-core20/18
/dev/loop3       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2318
/dev/loop13      46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/638
/dev/loop6      506M  506M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
/dev/loop17     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/microk8s/6809
/dev/loop15     9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/lp-build-snap/35
/dev/loop11      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop16     104M  104M     0 100% /snap/k8s/559
/dev/loop12     347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop14      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/1113
/dev/loop19     384K  384K     0 100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/49
/dev/loop18     104M  104M     0 100% /snap/k8s/552
/dev/loop1       11M   11M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/282
/dev/loop22     1.3G  1.3G     0 100% /snap/android-studio/157
/dev/loop21     350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
/dev/loop20      75M   75M     0 100% /snap/core22/1380
/dev/mmcblk0p1  511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
binfmt_misc        0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
tmpfs           378M  2.4M  375M   1% /run/snapd/ns
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/snapd/ns/canonical-livepatch.mnt
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/snapd/ns/snapd-desktop-integration.mnt
tmpfs           378M  116K  377M   1% /run/user/1000
gvfsd-fuse         0     0     0    - /run/user/1000/gvfs
/dev/sda1        57G   24K   54G   1% /media/aaron/dff958ee-9d7d-46d7-afc4-0b6f3fbf82fe
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt
tmpfs              -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/kubelet/pods/7f3a4a5d-9d40-4e8b-b44e-e7720af8b66f/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-47b9d
tmpfs              -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/kubelet/pods/91f96723-4d1f-4bd7-bfbb-10995e674a6d/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-7ghcs
tmpfs              -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/kubelet/pods/e709fcc4-c298-4653-8af4-83c1d8dcac67/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-njrsw
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/098d927837d11e69d4ba950853cac448600d2ec7df299ae5e7baed0bdc5c9957/shm
overlay            -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/098d927837d11e69d4ba950853cac448600d2ec7df299ae5e7baed0bdc5c9957/rootfs
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/a4529fcbb533077aef94c7b4c3f8ee7c329552ca9d646a01f2af1e69ca140acb/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/netns/cni-926d3f70-7adf-08b3-b8c9-83620c0d3a5a
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/a4a7d9ba8f330e1fce9ab1c63096866ee90cdee8dddc58f8b10f9117bca245f2/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/netns/cni-5b08937b-3289-fd97-0b66-b0e30a7c999f
overlay            -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/a4529fcbb533077aef94c7b4c3f8ee7c329552ca9d646a01f2af1e69ca140acb/rootfs
overlay            -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/a4a7d9ba8f330e1fce9ab1c63096866ee90cdee8dddc58f8b10f9117bca245f2/rootfs
overlay            -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/9c55a7ee6b936739df60dcbf25a6cda11d517ee94cf9f0f9da7c933d48472e23/rootfs
overlay            -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/9581ed09f50acd69f296cb9d3ac71c36a08c65fe1deacdf07c5142e397d0be54/rootfs
overlay            -     -     -    - /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/5ad1b0ef989283103c9af09db2d9aa3e7df38ade007c9ca50421370afa20dea7/rootfs

